# 'Continuous-state' Regime Switching Time Series Model?

Tags: time-series, hidden-markov-model

I've been thinking of an idea, and I've had a difficult time finding any information on it so I'm not sure if there's a literature on it, or if I have an awesome original idea, or a stupid idea of no use.

### Model

Essentially the basis would be a typical regime switching AR model of the form
$$x_t = \beta_{0,s} + \beta_{1,s} x_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t$$
Where $t$ is time, and $s$ denotes a specific regime.

I then modify it so $\beta_1, \beta_2$ would, rather than being associated with an element in a set of discrete regimes, be pulled from a distribution with parameters based upon the previous $\beta$ values. A simple version with normally distributed $\beta$ would be a model of the form
$$x_t = \beta_{0,t} + \beta_{1,t} x_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t$$
$$\textrm{where } \beta_{i,t} = \alpha+\gamma_{i,0} \beta_{0,t-1} +\gamma_{i,1} \beta_{1,t-1}+v_{i,t},$$
with $\alpha,\gamma$ values as static coefficients, and distribution term $v \sim N(0, \sigma_{\beta}^2)$.

Obviously there are a lot of modifications one could do, but I'm just trying to clearly demonstrate the sort of thing I have in mind.

Comment: That looks like a dynamic linear model or a time varying autoregression

Answer (score 0):

I've used MS_Regress for Matlab.  The author mentions it contains a wrapper for regime switching autoregressive models:

[MS_Regress for Matlab](https://github.com/msperlin/MS_Regress-Matlab)

You can find installation instructions for the author's R version at the following link.  The package is called 'fMarkovSwitching'.  Perhaps he has included similar functionality in R as his Matlab version.

[fMarkovSwitching](https://msperlin.github.io/pafdR/models.html)